# Having some issues recursively printing a complete list of a tree-like structure

Tags: go, recursion, struct, slice

I'm having trouble creating a structure for a CLI tool that will have *n* commands. Each command can have *n* subcommands, and each subcommand can have *n* more subcommands.

My issue is that, in Go, I'm struggling to figure out a way to create a recursive function to output the name of each command, along with each *n* subcommands + every *n* subcommands for that subcommand, in a complete list.

For example, I'm looking to get the following output:

```
1. command1
2. command2
3. command3
4. command3 subcommand1
5. command3 subcommand1 subcommand1
6. command3 subcommand2
```

Here is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type command struct {
    name        string
    parent      *command
    subcommands []*command
}

func getLastCommand(c command) command {
    for _, s := range c.subcommands {
        if len(s.subcommands) == 0 {
            return *s
        }
        return getLastCommand(*s)
    }
    return c
}

func main() {
    cmdBase1 := command{
        name: "base1",
    }

    cmdBase2 := command{
        name: "base2",
    }

    var (
        cmdBase3,
        cmdBase3Sub1,
        cmdBase3Sub1Sub1,
        cmdBase3Sub2 command
    )

    cmdBase3 = command{
        name:        "base3",
        subcommands: []*command{&cmdBase3Sub1, &cmdBase3Sub2},
    }

    cmdBase3Sub1 = command{
        name:        "base3:sub1",
        parent:      &cmdBase3,
        subcommands: []*command{&cmdBase3Sub1Sub1},
    }

    cmdBase3Sub1Sub1 = command{
        name:   "base3:sub1:sub1",
        parent: &cmdBase3Sub1,
    }

    cmdBase3Sub2 = command{
        name:   "base3:sub2",
        parent: &cmdBase3,
    }

    // root commands
    commands := []command{
        cmdBase1,
        cmdBase2,
        cmdBase3,
    }

    for _, c := range commands {
        last := getLastCommand(c)
        fmt.Println(last.name)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HZPRlSghfAY

Here is the current output:

```
base1
base2
base3:sub1:sub1
```

My desired output is with the above code is:

```
base1
base2
base3
base3:sub1
base3:sub1:sub1
base3:sub2
```

What do I need to change in my code so I can get my above desired output? Is there an algorithm or data structure that I could follow to solve this? I've tried depth-first and binary searching, but I can't seem to mold it to my structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple and elegant solution would be to "arm" `command` with a `print()` method. This could print its name, and range over its subcommands, calling their `print()` (which do the same):

```
func (c *command) print() {
    fmt.Println(c.name)
    for _, sc := range c.subcommands {
        sc.print()
    }
}
```

Then printing the commands in `main()` is just calling their `print()` method (`getLastCommand()` is not even needed / used):

```
for _, c := range commands {
    c.print()
}
```

This will result in your desired output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g5AF0CXqQCF)):

```
base1
base2
base3
base3:sub1
base3:sub1:sub1
base3:sub2
```

Note that of course `print()` doesn't have to be a method, it may be a regular function too, in which case it could look like this:

```
func print(c *command) {
    fmt.Println(c.name)
    for _, sc := range c.subcommands {
        print(sc)
    }
}
```

And the loop in `main()`:

```
for _, c := range commands {
    print(&c)
}
```

Result is the same, try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KyeIuX776NR).

I would also suggest to be consistent. If you decide to use pointer to `command`, do it everywhere (e.g. the `commands` slice in your `main()` stores non-pointers, that's why its element's address had to be taken to pass to `print()`).

Comment: Legend! Exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks :)